# Read All Emails In a Domain

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-workspace

I want to read all emails in my domain against a query using API. Currently, I am enumerating one user at a time and extracting all the emails for it

```
list(userId, includeSpamTrash=None, labelIds=None, maxResults=None, pageToken=None, q=None, x__xgafv=None)
```

This approach is not scalable as in the case of 1000+ users it will take a lot of time. I want to extract the emails for all users against a query but without enumerating userId

Answer (score 1):

The [message.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A1000%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) method does not return a full message object it only returns the message id and the thread id.

```
"messages": [
    {
      "id": "178a78eef21cc0fa",
      "threadId": "178a78eef21cc0fa"
    },
    {
      "id": "178a77fd677004b8",
      "threadId": "178a738e29b7812d"
    },
    {
      "id": "178a778d32097a98",
      "threadId": "178a738e29b7812d"
    },
```

If you want more information about the message then you will need to run a [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) which does return a full [message object](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message)

I guess what i am saying is this approach may not be scalable in your case but it is your only option.

You could try batching the requests but i haven't personally had much luck with [batching](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) you will need to check that the Python client library was updated to use the new batching endpoint Im not sure if they have updated it yet.

Comment: but still we have to enumerate all users. I couldn't find any way of directly getting emails for all the users within in the domain without enumerating each of them.

Comment: The way the api works is a request contains an authorization header which gives the request access to a users data.   A single request a single user.   You will never get more then one users data back for a single request.  Even batching will only be a single users data.   I understand what you are trying to do but its not visible within the realms of Oauth2